# how to pass a state to a container in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am learning react native and i am building an application. For some concepts, I am not able to understand where the magic happens. I am using redux store for the managing the data.

I have a stateless login component.

```js
export class Login extends Component {
   onChangeText = (key, value) => {
     this.props.user[key] = value
  }

  render() {
    const { user, fetchUserDetails } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Email'
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('email', val)}
          value={user.email}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Password'
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('password', val)}
          value={user.password}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.fetchUserDetails(user)}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my Login Container

```js
class LoginContainer extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Login/>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.loginReducer.user,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ...fetchUserDetails,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

my reducer looks like this:

```js
const initialState = {
  user: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }
}

const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_USER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        user: action.user
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
  return state
}

export default loginReducer
```

My actions look something like this:

```js
export const GET_USER = 'GET_USER'
export function fetchUserDetails (user) {
  console.log("executing fetch user action")
  if (user === '')
  {
    alert('please complete form')
  }
  return {
    type: GET_USER,
    user
  }
}
```

My root reducer:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loginReducer from './loginReducer'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

My configure Store:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'mykey',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
const store = createStore(persistedReducer)
const persistedStore = persistStore(store)

export default store
```

I need to have a stateless component which updates directly the state of the user attributes in the redux store. I am not able to follow how the state or actions will be passed to the Login component. Any Explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managing redux store in react-native is basically same as you do in react.

From what I understand you are trying to store user details in redux store on every onChangeText event and reflect the updated state in Login component.

Firstly you should use a separate action reducer pair for setting user details in redux. Also You most probably want to call some API on form submission and store the response in redux, For that you might need another pair of action and reducer. I'll leave that to you

Here's how u can manage user-details in redux...

Your stateless login component.

```
export class Login extends Component {
   onChangeText = (value, key) => {
     this.props.setUserDetails({
       ...this.props.user,
       [key]: value
     })
  }

  render() {
    const { user, onSubmitForm } = this.props
    console.log('user===>', this.props);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Email'
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText(val, 'email')}
          placeholderTextColor={'rgba(0,40,70,0.5)'}
          value={user.email}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Password'
          onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText(val, 'password')}
          placeholderTextColor={'rgba(0,40,70,0.5)'}
          value={user.password}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onSubmitForm(user)}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

...

Your Login Container.

```
class LoginContainer extends Component {
  onSubmitForm = () => {
    // Checking Validations
    const { name, email } = this.props;
    if (!name || !email) {
      alert('Please fill the form')
      return;
    }

    // call some API for verification and handle the response here
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Login
        user={this.props.user}
        setUserDetails={this.props.setUserDetails}
        onSubmitForm={this.onSubmitForm}
      />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.userReducer.user,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setUserDetails: payload => dispatch(setUserDetails(payload)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)
```

...

Your Reducer for setting user details

```
const initialState = {
  user: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_DETAILS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        user: action.user
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
  return state
}

export default userReducer
```

...

Your store will remain same and rootReducer should be

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  userReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

...

Finally your Action

```
export const SET_USER_DETAILS = 'SET_USER_DETAILS'

export function setUserDetails (user) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_USER_DETAILS',
    user
  }
}
```

...

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your solution but then it gives me this error that user.email is undefined in the Login component. In fact none of the properties are being passed to the Login component.

Comment: Have you setup the root-reducer properly. I'm assuming you have assigned a state named *userReducer* for your userReducer there.  Try checking the values in *LoginContainer*. Also check whether you are receiving proper values in action and reducer. If not than setup your root-reducer properly. Take help from this [docs.](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)

Comment: What do you mean by "state named userReducer" ? Code you posted in your answer consists of my user Reducer.

Comment: Redux provide you a function named "combineReducer", which combine all your reducers into one reducer which is then passed to your redux-store. it accepts an object mapping states with corresponding reducers. I've assumed you named your state same as your reducer's name i.e. *userReducer* like this *combineReducers({ userReducer: userReducer })* and then passed it to the store.

Comment: Yes, its already done but then again i just cant access it. I will make an edit by adding my root reducer file and configureStore file.

Comment: Try it now I changed few bits in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps:

**Login:**

You must NEVER update a component props inside the said component.

From the [React documentation](http://A%20React%20component%20should%20use%20props%20to%20store%20information%20that%20can%20be%20changed,%20but%20can%20only%20be%20changed%20by%20a%20different%20component.):

> Props are Read-Only

If you want your state (the truth) to be stored in the login component, then store it as a proper state and send this local state on submit:

```
onChangeText = (key, value) => {
   this.setState((state) => ({ ...state, [key] => value}))
}
```

However, if you want to store your state in redux, you will need to create an action that can be triggered to update the redux state. This action needs to be passed to your component props and called like this `onChangeText={val => this.props.onChangeText('email', val)}`

Also, your calling the `fetchUserDetails` function on render, where you should be passing a callback. `this.fetchUserDetails` does not exists, `this.props.fetchUserDetails` does. The login code becomes

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchUserDetails(user)}>
```

**Login Container:**

`mapDispatchToProps` must be a function that takes `dispatch` as first parameter OR an object where each function is an action creator. From the [Redux documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md):

> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

So the code you wrote:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ...fetchUserDetails,
}
```

Is equivalent to this code

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchUserDetails: (user) => dispatch(fetchUserDetails(user))
    },
}
```

The `dispatch` function is where the magic happens, every action that is dispatched is passed down to your reducers where you can create a new state based on the action.